# GeoServer Integrated GeoWebCache and Layer Group Mode

Tags: geoserver, wms, geowebcache

I've been told that in previous versions of GeoServer it was possible to cache the individual layers which make up a layer group and that requests for the layer group would then return the relevant tiles if they are seeded.

In the latest versions of GeoServer you can integrate the GWC with WMS and there are 4 options for layer group types. As far as I can tell the options work as follows:
 - single = this appears to generate a seperate tile cache for the layer group
 - named tree = same result as single
 - container tree = error, doesn't produce any tiles
 - Earth Observation tree = error, doesn't produce any tiles

Is it possible to cache the individual layers rather than the layer group in the latest versions of GeoServer or do I have to double up the file space and cache the tiles twice?

Do any of the layer group types impact the caching process or is that option unrelated to tile caching?